# Displaying distinct grouped table in report

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have a report with a basic table listing each row from a dataset.

I want to add a grouped summary table (by product and location) at the top:

```
PRODUCT  LOCATION  QUANTITY
Widget1  br1       10
Widget1  br2       1
Widget2  br1       12
```

You get the idea. Not sure what grouping option I can use as I'm inexperienced with the report viewer control.

Comment: Are you using report builder?

Comment: I'm working on an rdlc file in VS2012 using the visual editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own.

Right click on row -> Row Group -> Group Properties -> Sorting -> sort by Product A-Z, Location A-Z.

Still in Group Properties dialog. Go to General -> Set name to "Group".  Add group expressions: Group on Product, and Location.

Back in report builder, right click on the Quantity cell, select expression, set expression to `=RowNumber("Group")`.

That gives me exactly what I want :).